# Attach button to right side of screen that is responsive to the layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and I am looking for a way to attach a button to the right side of the screen. I have provided a picture to help give an understanding of what I am trying to accomplish. The button in the picture when clicked is attached to a panel that comes out of the right hand side of the screen.

[image]

Comment: What did you try until now to achieve what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To attach an element to the right side of the screen, all you need to do is use:

```
button {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
}
```